# Where do butterflies sleep?

Tags: neuroscience, entomology, sleep

Do butterflies (insects) sleep, and if so, where??

I have googled for information but didn't get an exact answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better to say that they go into an inactive, low metabolic state. This low metabolic state is often driven by the temperature in the air itself; ectothermic butterflies require outside heat-energy to become active. Basically they use this time to digest their food and produce sperm/eggs. ([reference](http://blog.perunature.com/2013/01/do-butterflies-sleep.html)). At night, or during inclement weather, most butterflies perch on the underside of a leaf (this provides them with a bit of shelter from the rain and makes them less noticeable to prey), crawl deep between blades of grass or into a crevice in rocks, or find some other shelter to rest ([reference](http://www.naba.org/qanda.html)).  In short, I would not call it sleeping but just a state of rest. Butterflies cant even close their eyes from the lack of eyelids ([reference](http://www.kidsbutterfly.org/faq/behavior/9)).