# What do spiders do all day?

Tags: behaviour

I found a question about ants sleeping - [Do ants or other insects sleep, and if so why?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21159/23783), but I don't think it really answers my question.

*For the question, I'm mostly referring to web-making spiders, say orb webs.*

---

So a spider set up shop inside my house late last year. It built a web high up in the corner and started catching moths and stuff. I know it's been there and it's the same spider because I've watched it grow.

But when the spider isn't **catching** something, **eating** or **building** a web - ***what is it doing?*** Just waiting for web vibration?

I imagine if it was outside it would be hiding or trying not to be prey. I also imagine it might be looking for a mate. What I can't figure out is what this spider does all day.

Why would it build a web where no other spiders are and then stay there for months doing nothing?

Comment: It is meditating. But the one outside my back door is plotting just when and how to scare me to death by jumping on my head. I can tell by looking deeply into the largest of its four pairs of eyes. Where is @Roland when we need them?

Comment: Why don't you think it could be hiding or trying not to be prey indoors? I doubt the spider is quite aware of the barriers your house provides to entry of certain predators, or that it has chosen a place that is less likely to be frequented by its conspecifics. I think what you are describing: building a web and waiting, is essentially the activity of "hunting" for a spider.

Comment: @BryanKrause - Indeed, house spiders are just that: house spiders.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I thought house spiders didn't have a long enough lifespan for the amount of time it has been here.

Comment: They can live about two years if they have food. And they can survive on really tiny things, like drain flies.